# Can I add custom model textures to entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to finish my work adding a **CustomModelTexture** to the Husk, but YouTube and other questions aren't helping me, and I want to not affect the Husk texture, a command like that: `summon husk ~ ~ ~ {CustomModelData:1}`, It's it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently edit entity textures with custom model data sadly.  But you could use custom model data to texture a item to make it look like a entity and put it on the husks head.  Then effect the husk with invisibility.  Now you have a custom entity.  To animate the custom entity is difficult.  I currently don't know how to do that.  There are videos on YouTube about animating custom models.  (For example one by cloud wolf). I think you would have detect if the mob is in motion with the motion nbt tag. That may be for be launched and not walking.  Or you could use the walk distance scoreboard.  That is my suggestion.  I hope this helps.